# Interpolation in polar coordinates

Tags: numerical-methods, polar-coordinates, interpolation, computational-mathematics

I have a grid (a map) of $(x_i,y_j)$ with some functional value defined at the grid points $f_{ij}=f(x_i,y_j)$. In this map, I would like to do interpolation so that i can calculate value of $f$ at some points in polar coordinates. I have read about multidimensional interpolation in the numerical recipes but they only discuss the interpolation on a rectangular grids not in polar coordinates. What I actually need is to determine the value of $f$ at some $(r,\varphi)$ polar coordinates.

One idea that i have is to determine the cartesian coordinates for the given $(r,\varphi)$ and use e.g. bilinear interpolation on the cartesian grid for the corresponding $(x(r,\varphi),y(r,\varphi))$ points. But i am not sure, if this is the correct approach.

I have found some topics on here but i cannot say they were very helpful. Can someone comment on how to approach this or point me to some literature?

Comment: It seems to me that you have a choice. Either work in $x,y$ representation, do the interpolation, then transform the result to polar coordinates. Or transform the grid to polar coordinates and do the interpolation in that representation. Both methods should work. Perhaps when you transform the grid, the spacing between points becomes unbalanced. That is something for you to check.